# Class of every same page on same website changes. I am trying scrape description from page

Tags: python, html, class, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import re
import json


title = []
pages = np.arange(1,13)

for page in pages:
    url = 'https://www.jobs.ch/en/vacancies/?page='+str(page)+'&term=python%20web'
    print(url)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    jobs = soup.find_all('a',  class_='sc-hGPAah Link-sc-1vy3ms6-1 jegSWD', href=True, title=True)
    for job in jobs:
        job_title = job['title']
        print(job_title)
        title.append(job_title)
        job_half_url = job['href']
        job_full_url = 'https://www.jobs.ch'+str(job_half_url)
        print(job_full_url)
        data = re.search(r"__INIT__ = (\{.*\})", requests.get(job_full_url).text).group(1)
        data = json.loads(data)
        # print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))
        for j in data["lists"]["jobs"].values():
            soup2 = BeautifulSoup(j["template"], "html.parser")
            # print(soup2)
            for t in soup2.find_all(class_="col-xs-12 col-md-9 col-md-push-3"):
                desc.append(t.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
                print(t.get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
```

> I am trying to **scrape** description of page. but every page changes it's div class name.
> in line for t in soup2.find-all(class_ = "here name changes"):

Comment: Yes, this is a common anti-scraping measure. You'll need to rely on something other than class names, or see if the website has an API.

Answer (score 2):

Use stable looking attributes/types and their relationship e.g.

```
print(soup2.select_one('.content-row > div:nth-child(1)').get_text(strip=True, separator="\n"))
```

Here I rely on the child div relationship to a more stable looking parent class.